# how to replace the manjaro original python3 environment

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, manjaro

I had installed anaconda(python3) by yaourt into my manjaro system. I know that manjaro contains python3 and python2 environment. Now I want to replace the manjaro original py3 environment to anaconda. How should I do.
Thanks to everyone for answering this question.

(I try to modify the PATH to anaconda, but it will also affect python2 environment. Finally I can't open gnome tweak tools because it is based on py2 installed in manjaro)

Comment: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: You should never overwrite your OS Python environment. Use Conda environments for your own individual projects.

Comment: thanks everyone for giving me a lot advices. You are right. I mean that if you want to start anaconda as soon as you open the terminal. you can just write down the activite shell code in ~/.bashrc. The code is "source /opt/anaconda/bin/activate root".(i use zsh, if it's same to you ,you should input it on ~/.zshrc)